# Why static string in .rodata section has a four dots prefix in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

For the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("Hello World1");
    return 0;
}
```

the generated assembly for calling printf is as follows (64 bits):

```
  400474:   be 24 06 40 00          mov    esi,0x400624
  400479:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
  40047e:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  400480:   e8 db ff ff ff          call   400460 <__printf_chk@plt>
  400485:   be 30 06 40 00          mov    esi,0x400630
  40048a:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
  40048f:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  400491:   e8 ca ff ff ff          call   400460 <__printf_chk@plt>
```

And the .rodata section is as follows:

```
Contents of section .rodata:
 400620 01000200 48656c6c 6f20576f 726c6400  ....Hello World.
 400630 48656c6c 6f20576f 726c6431 00        Hello World1.
```

Based on the assembly code, the first call for printf has the argument with address 400624 which has a 4 byte offset from the start of .rodata. I know it skips the first 4 bytes for these 4 dots prefix here. But my question is why GCC/linker produce this prefix for string in .rodata ? I am using 4.8.4 GCC on Ubuntu 14.04. The compilation cmd is just: `gcc -Ofast my-source.c -o my-program`.

Comment: Those aren't dots. objdump (or whatever you're using) is printing dots because there aren't valid characters there. (Same reason it displays dots for the null terminators)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For starters, those are not four dots, the dot just means unprintable character. You can see in the hex dump that those bytes are `01 00 02 00`.

The final program contains other object files added by the linker, which are part of the C runtime library. This data is used by code there.

You can see the address is `0x400620`. You can then try to find a matching symbol, for example you can load it into `gdb` and use the `info symbol` command:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x4005f8
_IO_stdin_used in section .rodata of /tmp/a.out
```

(Note I had a different address.)

Taking it further, you can actually find the [source for this in glibc](http://repo.or.cz/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/csu/init.c#l24):

```
/* This records which stdio is linked against in the application. */
const int _IO_stdin_used = _G_IO_IO_FILE_VERSION;
```

[and](http://repo.or.cz/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/generic/_G_config.h#l50)

```
#define _G_IO_IO_FILE_VERSION 0x20001
```

Which corresponds to the value you see if you account for little-endian storage.

Answer (score 2):

It does *not* prefix the data.  The `.rodata` can contain anything.  The first four bytes are [seemingly] a string, but it just happens to link there (i.e. it's for something else).  It is *unrelated* to your "Hello World"